# Creating wget in Domino

Tags: lotus-notes, wget, lotusscript

I am trying to implement a feature that returns a zip file upon calling an agent on Domino system. So domino is the webserver that returns a zip file.

A 3rd party app would use something like a `wget` statement to call a domino based system url and they would get a zip file.

Does anyone have an existing implementation of this kind of an idea where we can share thoughts on that or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the zip file in a document in a Notes database on the server. The URL will be of the form:

```
 www.yourHost.com/your Path/yourDatabase.nsf/viewUNID/docUNID/$File/yourFilename.zip
```

Use whatever tool you want to retrieve it.

(This assumes, of course, that the server has been properly set up to support HTTP.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is the way we are designing it by storing it on a temp record and call the URL. But there is a processing time here as we create a zip file based on the input parameters from the URL. So, need to tweak it to make sure that with one URL call, output will be a zip file.

Comment: What you can do is write your agent to store the zip file in the temp document and then send the correct URL back to the browser as a redirect. As I recall, if the only thing your agent puts into the response is the URL enclosed in square brackets (i.e., [www.etc.etc/etc/$File/filename.zip]), it will be processed as a redirect. The other way, again if I recall correctly, is by setting putting <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url=http://www.etc.etc/etc/$File/filename.zip" /> into the response.

Comment: Interesting coincidence... This question about redirecting just appeared: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002200/how-to-redirect-webpage-by-lotus-notes-java-agent

Comment: Thanks for the inputs again. Due to some increased processing time, we are not storing it on a notes doc as upload is taking a while for larger files. Instead we are creating zip and putting it on HTML folder and using print "[]" statement, pushing it back via the agent itself. So far, it works well under the test phase. Will get back with more feedback  as and when I get another approach.

Answer (score 0):

this can be achieved by using java.util.zip and a xpage

```
if (doc != null)
                {
                    Vector<String> attachments = (Vector<String>) s.evaluate("@AttachmentNames", doc);
                    if (attachments != null)
                    {
                        if (attachments.size() > 0)
                        {
                            HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) facesContext.getExternalContext().getResponse();
                            this.setHeaders(response, zipFileName);
                            ZipOutputStream zipOutStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.getOutputStream());
                            EmbeddedObject embeddedObj = null;
                            BufferedInputStream bufferInStream = null;
                            for (String attName : (Vector<String>) attachments)
                            {
                                embeddedObj = doc.getAttachment(attName);
                                if (embeddedObj != null)
                                {
                                    if (embeddedObj.getType() == EmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT)
                                    {
                                        bufferInStream = new BufferedInputStream(embeddedObj.getInputStream());
                                        int bufferLength = bufferInStream.available();
                                        byte[] data = new byte[bufferLength];
                                        bufferInStream.read(data, 0, bufferLength);
                                        ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(embeddedObj.getName());
                                        zipOutStream.putNextEntry(entry);
                                        zipOutStream.write(data);
                                        zipOutStream.closeEntry();
                                        bufferInStream.close();
                                        try
                                        {
                                            embeddedObj.recycle();
                                        } catch (Exception ex2)
                                        {
                                            OpenLogItem.logError(ex2);
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            zipOutStream.flush();
                            zipOutStream.close();
                        }
                        result = true;
                        facesContext.responseComplete();
                    }
                    doc.recycle();
                }



private void setHeaders(HttpServletResponse response,String zipFileName)
{
    try{
    response.setContentType("application/octet-stream");
    response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
    response.setHeader("Pragma", "Public");
    response.setHeader("Content-Description", "File Transfer");
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);
    response.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
    }
    catch(Exception ex)

    {
        OpenLogItem.logError(ex);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try this approach and let you know the feedback. Thanks for the code too.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs, following Mr. Richard's tip here as that approach is quicker for us. Appreciate your response.