# How to redirect webpage by Lotus Notes java agent?

Tags: java, lotus-notes

Users comes to a page by using following URL:

```
http://myswerver/mydb.nsf/myagent?OpenAgent
```

Now I want this Java agent check something in the db and if it meets some conditions then redirect user to another page. If not - load main page that is build by myagent. Here is my agent code:

```
PrintWriter pw = getAgentOutput();

if(myvar == 1){
    pw.flush();
    pw.println("Content-Type: text/html");
    pw.println("<html><head>");
    pw.println("<script>location.href=\"http://www.mypage.com\"</script>");
    pw.println("</head></html>");
}
```

The problem that it loads agents' page everytime even it redirects then. I do want to redirect immediately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is much easier: Whenever you want anything to redirect in Lotus Notes in the web, then you simply "print" the redirection url in brackets. Your code can be simplified like this:

```
PrintWriter pw = getAgentOutput();

if(myvar == 1){
    pw.flush();
    pw.println("[http://www.mypage.com]");
}
```

This will instantly redirect you to the url without visibly loading the "agent- page" first.

This would work in LotusScript- Agents as well as

```
print "[http://www.mypage.com]"
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Link.. It works great.. I just forgot about brackets.